# Meteor, how to send data to client non re-actively?

Tags: meteor

In my app, all the actions that user can do is subject to them logging in! but they still can see the content without being able to do anything. As you know the biggest overhead of meteor is Merge box. So if the users that are not logged in get their data in anyway rather than subscribe, the merge box overhead is going away!

Is it possible to use methods to get data? Is there a better way?
with current packages is it possible to do Server Side Rendering for this non reactive pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There several ideas presented [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/non-reactive-publications-in-meteor/5366).

Unless you really need collection semantics, I think the easiest solution is just to use a method to return the data. We do that in a number of places in our ap, when the value of reactivity is low and the performance penalty of using a subscription is high.

Comment: can it be combined with fast render?

Comment: I haven't used fast-render so, I'm not sure. Glancing through docs suggests it's designed for waiting on subscriptions rather than methods.